# Generalisation in databases

Tags: database-design, primary-key, db2, foreign-key

I am working on a Hospital Management project in DB2. I have one table for staff with a primary key of staff_id. The hospital has to have different staff... e.g doctors,nurses,e.t.c.

Is it better to create another table for doctors,one for nurses,etc or should I connect the appointment table, nurse_schedule, test_table, all directly to the staff table ??

Comment: From the very nature of the question, you do not have the experience to design a database for this task. If this is the US, the database design is highly affected by HIPAA regulation and needs someone with a minimum of ten years of database design to do the design effectivly given the very serious legal constraints on the system. Other countries would have other leagal requirements. If you had that experience you would never have asked this question which is database 101. This is not a design job for an amateur. You can get your company is serious legal trouble.

Comment: this is a college project work ... you're right i d'ont have much experience designing databases, but at least you could help ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think: general to general, specific to specific. If you are planning to add some table and this data is specific to nurses ONLY, so make reference to nurses. If it is a permissions list, use reference to general staff table or better users list. Generalization is a way to organize that we *want* to organize. In life it's more complicated.

[image]

Comment: but suppose the hospital is big.. how do we add new types of staff (who have different permissions) if we create a table for each specialization (doctor, nurse,etc) ...

Comment: @nkvp link staff(general) to permissions, because of all have permissions (doctors, nurses...)

Comment: A link table *does not* need a surrogate key...

Comment: YOu only need new more specif tables if you have data that needs to be stored about them. Nor do new types of staff come along frequently. If they do and you have new functionality for them ,then you wil of course need to build the db strucure to handle it just like you would need to build any application pages to handle what they do.

Comment: @garik in the diagram, in the staff to doctor and staff to nurse connections, there seems to be two primary keys on both sides of the relationship and no foreign key. how do we connect these?

Comment: @nkvp it's foreign key, but relation is one-to-one (staff is master, doctor is **one** detail)

Comment: @garik one more thing... any idea how to implement this relationship in db2 (or atleast in sql) (can we just use an ordinary foreign key relationship) ??

Comment: is it difficult to create relation in db2?

Comment: no, i know how to create a primary key - foreign key relation in db2. its same as mysql(almost). i don't know how to create the one-to-one relationship between one parent and multiple child tables. should we just use the same primary key-foreign key relationship?? can you pls help in mysql if possible.

Comment: it is just simple foreign key. in sql server it will be like so: `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[doctor]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_doctor_staff] FOREIGN KEY([doctor_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[staff] ([staff_id])`

Comment: @garik is it not wrong/bad design for a key to be both primary and foreign key??

Comment: @nkvp it is something like inheritance. please, read about Domain design

Answer (score 7):

First of all, if this is homework, please tag it as such.

Secondly if it's not homework and you're doing this in a professional environment, get a professional to do it (or at least to thoroughly scrutinize your final design). Schema design underpins your application design, and flows on from clarity in business requirements and how well you understand those requirements. If you don't completely and clearly understand the requirements, your schema is going to be miles off the mark.

And, to actually answer the question (at least as best I can with the information given), I'd keep the staff in one table, however you may want to create ancillary tables for each 'type' of staff member (doctor, nurse, janitor, admin, etc) to store data specific to that staff-member-type. To give an answer that's any more specific, the requirements need to be more specific.

Comment: no.. this is not homework.. this is a project (as stated above). i think you got the question.. exactly what i was thinking of. however, in that case, is it better to keep a common id for all staff for generality or should we have separate ids for doctor table, nurse table, etc e.g because a diagnosis can only be done by a doctor (doctor id can be used in the diagnosis table and not staff id).

Comment: One more doubt... Suppose the hospital is big.. how do we add new types of staff (who have different permissions) if we create a table for each specialization every time (doctor, nurse,etc) (sorry for the repetition below)

Comment: @nkvp: If only a doctor can make a diagnosis, then the table that stores diagnoses should have a foreign key to the doctors table, not to the staff table. You don't need a different id; you just need the right foreign key.  The right person to design a hospital system would already know that. (That's an observation, not a criticism.)

Comment: kk..i know that... i was just asking if there is another way ...

Comment: If you have clear requirements, they should cover all the use cases and all the staff types for the system. If you don't have clear requirements, that's deadly quicksand for most software projects. (To go slightly deeper, it's entirely possible to program an application to be flexible enough to accept any new staff type - except if you go that far, configuring the application becomes programming in itself.)

Comment: oh... so is it much better to predefine all the required staff when creating the schema itself?

Comment: For that, I'm going to fall back to "it depends". If you have a clear idea of what's going on and what your application needs to do, then yes, pre-define everything. If you're floundering around in the dark with vague guidelines, then you need more flexibility.